# Attaching a heatsink to a DRV8825 stepper motor driver

Tags: heatsink

I'm using the [Pololu DRV8825 Stepper Motor Driver](http://www.pololu.com/product/2132) to control a [NEMA 17 Steppermotor](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Nema-17-1-7A-2-55V-Motor-ACT-17HS4417-Rep-rap-Nema17-Bipolar-/281122696759) with an Arduino.  The stepper motor requires 1.7A current.  According to the driver specs on the Pololu website, if the current draw is higher than 1.5A per coil, I will need a heat sink.

The problem is that I'm not sure exactly where the heatsink should be mounted, or how to mount it.  Furthermore, the driver is very small and most heatsinks i've seen are larger than it.  Is there a specific type of heat sink that I should use for this device?  Where should it be mounted?  How should I mount it?

Front Side:

[image]

Back Side:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is a little bit confusing but the pad to place a heat sink to, is on the under side of the PCB. The pad at the text "md20b".

Maybe you could use small heat sinks for computer graphics card memories? They can be attached with thermal conductive double sided tape.

Doing a Google image search for drv8825 heatsink gave a couple of hints on how to do this. Apparently you put the driver board on a couple of pin header risers, and/or place the PCB upside down.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Usually they come with the carrier boards. As shown, it's just popped on the top.

If using standoffs, a second heat sink also with double-sided thermal tape (usually provided), could be attached to the "bottom." This would sandwich the IC chip between two of those heat sinks:
[image]